# runInstaller permission denied

Tags: linux, oracle11g, installation, permission-denied, oracle-data-integrator

Im trying to install oracle data integrator into the linux server through my laptop but getting this error.I have give permission to read,write and execute for runInstaller but getting and error "permission denied". So what I have miss..

[execute ODI runInstaller for linux but getting error "permission denied"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FawXI.png)

Comment: You see that the error is against `install/linux64/runInstaller`, which the file you are calling is invoking - not the file that you already changed? What is the ownership and permissions on the install directory contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runInstaller calls the appropriate installer from /install folder. You should give permissions to required file. In your case it is

```
[YOUR_ODI_PATH]/install/linux64/runInstaller
```

As I see you have given 775 to runInstaller so you may give same permission to all /instal folder I suppose, but this is not required.

Answer (score 0):

the path where the oracle runInstaller is
example:
chmod u+x runInstaller
chmod -R 777 "the path where the oracle runistaller is"
./runinstaller.sh